# CS50 Finance History Problem with SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, cs50

I don't understand why I can't SELECT the 'transaction' column from my TABLE portfolio. I created a TABLE using the syntax below:

```
CREATE TABLE 'portfolio' ('transaction' integer primary key autoincrement, 
'datetime' datetime, user_id bigint, 'symbol' varchar(5), 'price' numeric(8, 
2), 'shares' integer, 'total' numeric(8, 2));
```

The transaction keeps a running count of buy/sell orders. When I have transaction in the SELECT statement, it gives me an error, see below:

```
RuntimeError: near "transaction": syntax error [SQL: 'SELECT transaction, 
datetime, symbol, shares, price FROM portfolio WHERE user_id = 2'] 
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

If I don't include transaction in the python code, then everything works and the table is displayed on the webpage. What is preventing me from selecting transaction? In the code, I included transaction.

```
@app.route("/history")
@login_required
def history():
    """Show history of transactions"""
    #create table
    history = db.execute("SELECT transaction, datetime, symbol, shares, price FROM portfolio WHERE user_id = :user_id", user_id = session["user_id"])

    history_info = []
    for info in history:
        transaction = info["transaction"]
        datetime = info["datetime"]
        symbol = info["symbol"]
        shares = info["shares"]
        price = info["price"]
        total = abs(shares * price)
        history_info.append({"transaction":transaction, "datetime":datetime, "symbol":symbol, "shares":shares, "price":price, "total":total})

    return render_template("history.html", history_info = history_info)
```

The html below is what will be displayed on the webpage. Currently, I left off the transaction.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    History
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th>Purchase Date/Time</th>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Shares</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for stock in history_info %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ stock.datetime }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock.symbol }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock.shares }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock.price }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock.total }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
   </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I would think `transaction` would be a reserved word. Try putting it in brackets `[transaction]` and see if that works for you.

Comment: That did it. [transaction] in the SELECT statement. Unfortunate I decided to choose a reserved word as my variable name, but at least now I know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved....

`transaction` is a reserved word.

Try putting it in brackets `[transaction]` and see if that works for you.